# не срабатывает e.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю загрузку файлов через `drag&drop`

```
$('.new-pl-content')
    .on('dragover', function () {
        $(this).addClass('pl-content-over');
        $('span', this).hide();

    })
    .on('dragleave', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('pl-content-over');
        $('span', this).show();
    })
    .on('drop', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

не срабатывает `preventDefault` и файл открывается ссылкой в браузере. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: А сниппет добавить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты должен отменить все события.

```
$("html").on("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('dragging');
});

$("html").on("dragleave", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).removeClass('dragging');
});

$("html").on("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("Dropped!");
});
```

Comment: Вызвать всё что есть, так, на всякий случай?

Comment: @Qwertiy Можешь проверить каждый на его отменяемость `event.originalEvent.cancelable;` и убрать лишние `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Я про то, действительно ли для поставленной задачи нужно вызывать оба метода (`preventDefault` и `stopPropagation`) в каждом из трёх обработчиков?

Comment: @Qwertiy `event.stopPropagation()` блокирует последующие обработчики. Тут он необязателен.